# UIAccessibility implementation with a large flowchart- ios

Tags: accessibility, uiaccessibility

I am trying to make my app accessible in ios.  I have some large complex images (flowcharts and tables). How would I go about making this image accessible if there are different elements within the image? I want them to be able to click on different parts of the image to hear different accessibility hints, rather than one hint for the whole image which may not be very helpful.

I thought about making blank labels and placing them over the image in the right places and writing the hints in these blank labels, but just wondering if there is a better way to do it. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think you will find a single answer both iOS and Android. Therefore I think that this questions should be two different questions.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make the contents of an image accessible. The best solution would be to adopt the `UIAccessibilityContainer` protocol and return [accessibility elements](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAccessibilityElement_Class/Reference/Reference.html) representing each node in the flowchart. The [Accessibility Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/) contains a section titled, [*Make the Contents of Custom Container Views Accessible*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008785-CH102-SW10). By adopting the `UIAccessibilityContainer` protocol, you can describe arbitrary regions of the flowchart as you would any view.